# upgrading from devise 1.5 to 2.0 : cannot login anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

First I'm quite new to ruby and rails...

I have a little application working with devise 1.5.4. I tried to upgrade to 2.0 but now authentication is failing in development mode (tests seem to be ok !?).
I searched the web quite extensively I think but found nothing. So I tried debugging (first time in ruby :) : the only thing that occured to me is that the only devise "strategy" used is rememberable and that there is no access to the database in the log.

log:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-17 15:47:22 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B0YUlSTdLU5vHkSuB4n78rM4ikyiLzTR0PgZmkSVzro=", "user"=>{"email"=>"member001@labandprocess.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 52ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B0YUlSTdLU5vHkSuB4n78rM4ikyiLzTR0PgZmkSVzro=", "user"=>{"email"=>"member001@labandprocess.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Rendered devise/_links.erb (0.4ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.7ms)
Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (4.5ms)
Rendered shared/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (27.2ms)
Rendered shared/_user_status.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 194ms (Views: 57.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

I made a diff between the 2 versions of my application, and the only thing that has changed beside the views and devise.rb (which is in both case the default one, i'm quite sure) is the migration :

After (2.0):

```
def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
        ## Database authenticatable
        t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
        t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

        ## Recoverable
        t.string   :reset_password_token
        t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

        ## Rememberable
        t.datetime :remember_created_at

        ## Trackable
        t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
        t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
        t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
        t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
        t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

        ## Encryptable
        # t.string :password_salt

        ## Confirmable
        t.string   :confirmation_token
        t.datetime :confirmed_at
        t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
        t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

        ## Lockable
        t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
        t.string   :unlock_token                   # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
        t.datetime :locked_at

        ## Token authenticatable
        # t.string :authentication_token


        t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
end
```

Before (1.5) :

```
def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
        t.confirmable
        t.database_authenticatable :null => false
        t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
        t.recoverable
        t.rememberable
        t.trackable
        # t.encryptable
        # t.token_authenticatable

        t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    #add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
end
```

and I seed data in dev mode with this:

```
User.create!(
  :email => 'member001@xxx.com',
  :password => 'mmmmmm'
).confirm!
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but when I upgraded to Devise 2.0 I had forgotten that I had customized the attribute used for login. I had changed it from the default :email to the more generic :login, so that users could log in with a username or an email address. Anyway, it turned out that after the upgrade my login form view was passing in :email when my model was still expecting :login.

Comment: thanks but i double checked and that's not the case: `# config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after several hours of comparison, I came to the conclusion that maybe the version of rails is the culprit. I was using 3.1.3 but after upgrading to 3.2.1 (with some other dependencies: i18n_routing and kaminari) it's working...

this is certainly not the main reason since the devise documentation states that rails 3.1
is compatible with devise 2.0, but it's working for now :)